# angularJS textAngular input box loses focus after entering text

Tags: angularjs, input, focus, textarea, richtextbox

I'm having an issue with an input box losing focus after entering a character. This only happens when the text angular RTB is selected first and then the input box.

Here's a link to a plunker demonstrating the issue.
http://plnkr.co/edit/m5A6ReSXbpmEEeheXV3W?p=preview

```
<p>Focus on textarea second and then begin typing</p>
<textarea id='textarea1' stop-event="touchend"></textarea>
<p>Focus on the RTB first</p>
<text-angular ng-model="content1" stop-event="focusout"></text-angular>
```

Thank you in advance for your response,
Jonathan

Comment: I think you might wanna ask this question in github as well.

Comment: @maxisam, I have. I'm just covering all my bases by posting it on here as well. Here's a link to the github post. https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/issues/505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should be fixed in the most recent version, v1.3.0.
Issue with same root cause: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/issues/468

EDIT: I monitor both github issues and a search for newest textAngular questions, I'm on GMT+13 so you may have to wait a day for a response but I usually get back to people within 24 hours in the week.